# Apache Beam 2.9 writing to Avro files to multiple directories on GCS with writeDynamic

Tags: apache-beam

I'm using Beam 2.9.0 to write Avro files to multiple directories. I have some "Event" class which has a field called "Id" a String. I want to group them by "Id" and write to their individual directory.

I am unable to figure how to define the "DestinationT" in

```
Class FileIO.Write<DestinationT,UserT>
```

Below is what I'm trying

```
FileIO.<String, Five9Event>writeDynamic()
                .by((SerializableFunction<Event, String>) in -> in.getId())
                .via(Contextful.fn(SerializableFunctions.<Event>identity()), //There is no conversion here
                        AvroIO.sink(Event.class))
                .withNumShards(1)
                .withNaming(id -> new CustomeFileNaming(type) //Is this where a directory is specified??
                .withTempDirectory("")//Some Temp Directory
                .withDestinationCoder(AvroCoder.of(Event.class, Event.SCHEMA$))//???
```

All the destinations should have the same Avro Schema coder.

The line

```
.withDestinationCoder(AvroCoder.of(Event.class, Event.SCHEMA$)
```

is not working as it expects Coder for DestinationT (String in my case) and not Coder for UserT (Event in my case). If the DestinationT is just used to group, I can't figure why we would need a Coder for it vs the actual payload we are writing to a file.

The signature in FileIO.write

```
FileIO.Write<DestinationT,UserT>    withDestinationCoder(Coder<DestinationT> destinationCoder)
Specifies a Coder for the destination type, if it can not be inferred from by(org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction<UserT, DestinationT>).
```

What is the exact semantics of DestinationT and if it is just some user defined type why is a Coder needed for it?

Comment: Not very familiar with Avro use case but looking at `AvroIOTest` ( https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/2bf5eadff02f9effdd299c867d6e476594ddeb22/sdks/java/core/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIOTest.java#L1075 ) and `FileIOTest` the desination coder is `StringUtf8Coder`: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/315b1bcfaaa69c19817fb291efdb0ca611d3aff0/sdks/java/core/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIOTest.java#L439

Comment: Ah, that's probably because in those cases the input is in strings as well

Answer (score 1):

I got this working, but I still can't answer why we need a DestinationCoder

```
FileIO.<String, Event>writeDynamic()
            .by((SerializableFunction<Event, String>) in -> in.getId())
            .via(Contextful.fn(
                        SerializableFunctions.<Event>identity()
                    ),
                    Contextful.fn(
                            (dest) -> AvroIO.sink(Event.class)
                            ))
            .withNumShards(1)
            .withTempDirectory(getTempDirectory())
            .withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
            .withNaming((dest) -> new CustomeFileNaming(dest, config))
```

The AroIO.sink I believe would set the write Coder for the payload.The DestinationT being a String I just used StringUtfCoder.of()

Comment: The docs for withDestinationCoder mention, "if it cannot be inferred from `by`". Lambda expressions don't supply sufficient type information. You would need to create a concrete subclass of SimpleFunction (`new SimpleFunction<Event, String {...`) in order to have type information be inferable. See https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.9.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/SimpleFunction.html